# Storyboard map not displaying or spanning specified region

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have been working on a program where on clicking a cell in my uisplitview a map which centers on a specfic region is loaded.  This worked fine HOWEVER. becuase of new functionality the need arose to put my xib into my storyboard. Nowm when i click the cell to call my map...the map does load but it does not center on the region it is supposed to and i have no idea why since that code appears to run (added breakpoint)

Below is the code that is run when the "Natural" field is selected. (the commented code is my orginal code...notice the variables i pass in) Below it is the code to sergue

In closing, I am not exactly sure why the map does not work as expected when I am using  `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryMap" sender:self];`  but works when i use

```
mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController    alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0 option:@"na"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:NO];
```

Only difference is when i use the sergue the `init` method (code posted at the bottom) doesnt run. but as i said before adding breakpoints shows me that the code in `viewDidLoad` does run

```
if ( ([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"Natural"])) {

 //    mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController      alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0 option:@"na"];
      //      [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:NO];
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryMap" sender:self];   
        }
```

**Then in said Sergue** Notice how i pass in those variables again. (im wondering if something is wrong with doing this here

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"countryMap"]) {
         mapViewController *transferViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
        transferViewController.location=0;
        transferViewController.option=@"na";

    }
}
```

**Then in view did load of the map**
location does evaulate to 0 and the breakpoint shows me that all this code is being stepped thru but the region of the coordinates i supplied isnt what is being shown.( the the span or region) 
(however when i call my old xib it works fine)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    if (location==0)
    {

         CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
         location1.latitude=(double)15.435786;
         location1.longitude=(double)-61.318447;


                    MKCoordinateRegion region;
                    MKCoordinateSpan span;
                    span.latitudeDelta=0.50;
                    span.longitudeDelta=0.40;
                    region.span=span;
                    region.center= location1;

                    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
                    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
               }
}
```

**INIT of my mapview**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil location:(int)num option:(NSString *)row
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.location=num;
        self.option=row;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What region is the map showing? Have you checked that mapView is not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar its loading with the map of the united states. Placed a break point on line  [mapView regionThatFits:region]; and it is indeed nil. Its not nil when i load my map the old way thou

Comment: Is mapView an IBOutlet? Did you hook it up in IB?

Comment: @rdelmar why yes i did. it is an IBOutlet. i still see it in the storyboard thou

Comment: So, you say that a log if mapView is nil, but the IBOutlet is hooked up (not just present) in the storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar shall delete my mapview and hook up it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments, the only logical explanation is that the IBOutlet for mapView is not hooked up. If you move a view from a xib file to a storyboard, any IBOutlets hooked up to the file's owner will not transfer with the view, since the file's owner doesn't exist in the storyboard. Therefore, you need to remake any outlets that were connected to the file's owner.